# Determining a subset of user's whose scores have improved using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

To start, I'm not sure if SQL is the best way to go about this, but given that my data is currently in a Postgres table, I figured that solving this problem using SQL would be the most logical place to start. I'll start out with my problem in plain english:

> **Problem statement in english:** I have a bunch of users (> 1 million) taking daily tests on my app. Their scores range from 0 to 100. I have about 5 years of this data. I would like to know which users have improved "most significantly" during this time.

There are quite a few things that I should elaborate on:

1. Improvement is arbitrary, but let's say that by "improvement" I mean that the average scores between the first N tests and the last N tests is at least D.
2. This means that there must be at least 2N rows for a user, but let's say that for a user to be eligible for analysis, they must have taken at least M * N tests. Finally, the difference between the first test and last test should be at least Y years.

To summarize, we have:

1. **N**: The number of tests we are averaging to determine initial and final performance scores.
2. **M**: Will be multiplied by N to determine the minimum number of tests that a user must have taken to be eligible for this analysis.
3. **D**: A threshold for filtering out top performers.
4. **Y**: The number of years that a user must have participated for.

## Test table schema (relative parts)

1. `user_id (UUID)`: The ID of the user who took this test
2. `score (INT)`: The score on this day's test
3. `created_at (DATETIME)`: The test date (one per day per user)

## My question

What would be a good way to query this in SQL?

Ideally the solution would be relatively fast (run within less than a minute or so). I can add table indices or make any other similar structural changes if required.

## My thoughts so far

I feel like there may be a way to create groups by a user_id, but only show the groups passing the initial constraints:

1. Having at least N * M entries in the group
2. Difference between the first and last entries being at least Y

But after that, I'm really not sure. Are there ways to create sub-groups within a group, potentially adding a new "average score" attribute for that group? (Even getting this far *could* be sufficient if it's not possible to omit results where the difference between first and last score averages are at least Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do this in SQL using window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select userid,
       avg(score) filter (where seqnum_asc <= @n) as first_n_avg,
       avg(score) filter (where seqnum_desc <= @n) as last_n_avg
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by date) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by date desc) as seqnum_desc,
             count(*) over (partition by userid) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= @M * @N
group by userid
having max(testdate) >= min(testdate) + @Y * interval '1 year'
order by (last_n_avg - first_n_avg) desc;
```

You can add the condition `(last_n_avg - first_n_avg) >= @D` to the `having` clause.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. I want to take a bit of time this afternoon to carefully understand this and will definitely either write back for clarification or upvote/select this answer. Thank you!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think you missed a desc in your second row_number()

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks again! I was also curious - is there a way to index this table to make the query run faster? I'm not familiar with how this is running under-the-hood, so I could see userid possibly being one way to index (in the case each group is done individually internaly), but if you have any insight there that'd be great. (It'll take a long time for the index to be created on this table, so I'd prefer to not be blindly guessing)

Comment: @wheresmycookie . . . Maybe.  You could try indexes on `(userid, testdate asc)` and `(userid, testdate desc)` to see if that helps.  However, you need to process all the data and use an aggregation, so it might not help that much.